# Rails rolling back twice every time I try to post Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, post

I am trying to create an app that allows users to make lists of items and view only the lists they themselves have created. Every time I press submit on the form this happens

```
Started POST "/lists" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-18 15:56:40 -0400
Processing by ListsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VnsMdQq3mw5XabkYCZFTgvgwFc3H89paHA0VE5gunFbiMfa0xGr0p1GEZDHc3yemwBx07K1h4CXuS0l5XL1VbA==", "list"=>{"income"=>"12", "put_into_savings"=>"12", "month"=>"12", "year"=>"21"}, "commit"=>"Create List"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering lists/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered lists/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.3ms)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 269ms (Views: 222.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
```

Here is all my code:

```
lists_controller.rb
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @lists = @user.lists
  end

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @list = List.create(list_params)

    if @list.save
      redirect_to home_url
    else
      render :new
  end
end

  private

  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:income, :put_into_savings, :month, :year)
  end
end
```

lists/new.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for List.new do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :income %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :income %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :put_into_savings %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :put_into_savings %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :month %><br />
      <%= f.number_field :month %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :year %><br />
      <%= f.number_field :year %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170818185700) do

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "item_name"
    t.integer "item_cost"
    t.string "item_waste"
    t.string "item_group"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "income"
    t.integer "put_into_savings"
    t.string "month"
    t.string "year"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "Item_id"
    t.integer "User_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "name"
  end

end
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root 'home#index'
get 'home' => 'home#index'

resources :lists
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Here is my list model:

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
  belongs_to :user
end
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Yes also what is the database you are using

Comment: From you schema I can see you add associations in List table to User and Item (user_id and item_id), but I can not find where you are adding them to your List when saving it.

Comment: Right now I am using the default database that comes when you /rails new. and I was not aware you had to add user_id and item_id during the save because that was dealt with by the associations in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having logic problem with your model association.

Assuming that a List could have more than one Item, you shouldn't have declared your table List with the attribute item_id. (Doing that it means a List could ONLY have one item). I recommend you read [ruby-on-rais-guide-for-associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

For the problem with the user_id, you need to explicit declared the user_id in your list object (considering that you want to associate a List with a User in the moment the List is created). One way to do it could be:

```
def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)
    @list[:user_id] = current_user.id # Considering you add this method
    if @list.save
      redirect_to home_url
    else
      render :new
  end
```

And add some validation in model:

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

It seems you need to read more about validation too [ruby-on-rais-guide-for-validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). About your twice rollback, it is unclear the reason, but fixing you association and validations problems, I think you can fix it.

Try read more about rails, the problem you are having are really basic. Good luck!

**UPDATE**:

As suggested by at0misk answer, to solve the problem with twice rollback:

In List controller:

```
@list = List.new(list_params)
# instead of @list = List.create(list_params)
```

The create method create a new object and save immediately. So, rails was trying to save twice, in the method create first, then in the method save in sequence.

Comment: I'll definitely read up more on ruby and thanks for the link, but the solution you have given me just throws me a new error:

syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end validates: user_id, presence: true ^

Comment: I will fix it in a minute. Sorry

Comment: @firewire167 fixed!

Answer (score 0):

In your create method, you're calling create and then calling save.  [Create](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class) creates an object and saves it to the database, so calling save is redundent.

Have you checked to see if your record is saving?  If it is then this is definitely what's wrong.  I prefer to use this pattern, using new instead of create, and then attempting to save in an if block:

```
  def create
       @list = List.new(list_params)
       if @list.save
            redirect_to home_url
       else
            render :new
       end
  end
```

Comment: This fixes it trying to save twice and rolling back twice, but it still doesn't save to the database.

Comment: The other answer currently on this page will deal with your validations, he is correct that you are not appropriately associating your records.